# SVN: how can I merge changes to a local repository to a master repository, preserving history?

Tags: svn, git-svn

For reasons to long to describe here, I created a local SVN repository, copied the contents of a remote repository, and make a total of 60 commits to it. In the mean time, the remote repository hasn't changed a single bit. Now I want to get those 60 commits in the remote repository. What is the best way to achieve this?

I've been looking for a solution. First thing I found was svnsync, but it will only work for a new empty repository.

Some similar questions were answered with 'use git-svn', without an explanation how this should work. The problem I get is that I end up with 2 unrelated branches in GIT. Using git-replace I should be able to mark the ancestor of the local branch in the remote branch, but in a small-scale test it results in a large number of merges. 
As a last resort I could write a shell-script that gets all patches from the local repository and apply them to the remote repository. It should be somewhere on the internet, but I can't find it.

In a future scenario I'd always use GIT to get a local repository, it would have saved a lot of trouble.

---

To elaborate on my small-scale git-svn test:

- create SVN repository svn-original, check out, make a few commits
- create SVN repository svn-local, copy contents of svn-original checkout, commit, make a few other commits
- since I'm on windows, use svn-serve to create a server for svn-original at the default port, and svn-local on port 1234

Then I did this in a console:

```
cd temp/git
git svn init --prefix=svn-original –R svn-original svn://localhost/ --stdlayout 
git svn init --prefix=svn-local –R svn-local svn://localhost:1234/ --stdlayout
git svn fetch svn-original
git svn fetch svn-local
git checkout -b svn-original svn-original/trunk
git checkout -b svn-local    svn-local/trunk
git log svn-local --oneline
#  find the commit that adds code from the original
git log svn-original --oneline
#  find the last commit
git-replace <first-local> <last-original>
```

This doesn't work: the last commit of svn-original is now shown in gitk as part of svn-local. Merging results in merge-conflicts, and dcommit fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svnrdump dump --incremental file:///path/to/local/repository -r 42:HEAD |
svnrdump load https://svn.example.org/path/to/remote/repository
```

See the following chapter in the SVN book for more details: [Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)

Comment: This looks like the solution. It even allows to do this on a part of the repository, but if I try that locally, it fails for not finding 'trunk': `C:\svn-merge-test>svnrdump dump --incremental file:///C:svn-merge-test/svn-local/trunk -r 2:HEAD | svnrdump load file:///C:/svn-merge-test/svn-original/trunk`
. This ends with output: `svnrdump: E160016: Path 'trunk' not present`

Comment: @mbvlist: Which of the two commands returns the error? Is `2` the first revision committed to `svn-local`, both repositories are identical up to revision 1, and there are no further revisions in `svn-original`?

Comment: The error comes from the second command. In this testcase everything is exactly the same: I added the files immediately under /trunk. For the real deal where I try to solve the problem I added the content of `http://original/repo/Driver/Product/trunk/*` in `file:///path/to/local/trunk/*`. So I'm afraid this solution needs more trickery to get it working

Comment: @mbvlist: You can fix the above error by removing the path segment from the target URL, i.e. `svnrdump load file:///C:/svn-merge-test/svn-original/`.

Comment: So svnrdump can't change the path. In the SVN book link you gave, there's a section that describes how to change the file for a changed path. So it can be done. I'll verify that tomorrow.

Comment: So I did this in cmd (svnrdump doesn't work from cygwin): `svnrdump dump -r5:57 --incremental "file:///c:/Path/To/Repo" > driver5-57.dump`
Then I performed some find/replace in cygwin: `sed -b -i 's_\(Node-.*path.*\)trunk/Wrong/Path/To/Root_\1Right/Path/To/Root_' driver5-57.dump`.